# How to pass 'User Password' as parameter in function?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to create users with a Function in Postgres. PostGres does not allow me to set a user's password with a parameter.

I've tried casting the parameter to all kinds of different types. Quoting literal on it. Nothing works.

Code:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
    userlogic_add_user(user_password text)

    ALTER USER user_name WITH user_password;
```

The error msg I receive is Syntax related. But it has something to do with user_password.

The entire code obviously looks a bit different, but these are the parts of interest.

Comment: Does `user_name` work as a variable?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can always try [executing a dynamic command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN):

```
EXECUTE ('ALTER USER ' || quote_ident(user_name) || ' WITH PASSWORD ' || quote_ident(user_password) || ';')
```